# Using absolute URLs in the Top Link Bar

Tags: navigation, url, hyperlink, top-link-bar

When I include absolute URLs in the top link bar (i.e. ones that start with a slash), they are treated as relative when using the bar, inherited, in subsites.

Is there a way to make it treat these as *actual* absolute URLs, and not relative?

Answer (score 2):

Use "../yoururl/targetlocation", with those two dots.

Edit: Or you could also use the complete URL, e.g. `http://sitecollection/subsite/`

Comment: Good idea, but I think the problem is that I don't know from what depth the links will be used, so I don't know how far to go back up the hierarchy (keeping in mind that the same bar is used in all sites).

Comment: Check my updated answer - in that case the recommendation would be to use full URLs.

Comment: Hm, I'm afraid that won't work because the domain name is going to change for the site in question. Anyway, I think I've figured it out (see below).

Answer (score 0):

Absolute links to subsites that don't exist are treated as relative, but those that point to existing subsites work correctly. The trouble is that this doesn't change once the missing subsite has been created, so the trick is to actually remove the link and create a new one (even though its text and URL are just the same).

This seems silly, so I'm not going to mark it as the right answer yet, in case someone can point out the obvious that I'm missing! `:-)`